# Maximum modulus principle for this function

Tags: complex-analysis

$Q)$ Say $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \vert 1 \lt \Vert z \Vert \lt 2\}$ and $\bar D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \vert 1 \leq \Vert z \Vert \leq 2\}$

Plus $f$ is a analytic on $D$ with $f(z) \neq 0 (\forall z \in \bar{D})$

$\vert f(z) \vert  =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{$\vert z \vert =1 $ } \\
4 & \text{$\vert z \vert =2 $ }
\end{cases}$ ,  $f(1+i)=2$.  Find the $f(z)$

---

My lecturer claimed $f(z) = iz^2$ in his note.  But In my thought this question and his answer are really nonsense, themselves.

First reason at the point of the question itself, the $f$ is a analytic on bounded open- connected $D$. Then We can apply the maximal modulus thm, So the $\vert f \vert$ have a maximal value(or the minimal Value) at the boundary of the $D$. But since the $\vert f \vert$ is a maximal at the $1+i \in int(D)$, $f$ should be constant. Hence $f = 2$ on $D$. But the it is contradict with the $\vert f \vert =1$ on $\vert z\vert =1$, because $lim_{\vert z \vert \to 1^+ } \vert f(z) \vert  =2 \neq \vert f \vert =1$ (I.e. $f$ is not continuous on the $D$, But the question supposing the $f$ is analytic[continuous])

Second reason at the point of his answer itself, Supposing his question makes sense, $g(z) = \frac
{f(z)}{z^2}$ is a analytic on $D$. Then By maximal modulus thm, $g(z) = c$ $s.t.$ $\vert c \vert =1$ . So,  $f(z) = cz^2$ And next using the condition $f(1+i)=2$, $c=-i$ Not $c = i$
Therefore my answer is $f(z) = -iz^2$

Is my thought right? (I.e. Are his things are totally nonsense not only question but also solution even though assuming his question is right?)

Thanks.

Comment: $|f(1+i)| = 2 < 4$, so what makes you think that $|f|$ has a maximum at $z=1+i$? – The second part of your question is correct, it should be $f(z) = -iz^2$.

Comment: Ahh I made a serious mistake calculating the norm of the real number. Thank you @MartinR

Comment: So the only “nonsense” (using your terminology) is a sign error in your lecturer's notes...

Comment: @MartinR, yes it is.